# Setting cookies in django without a response

Tags: python, django

I want to be able to set a cookie on my django site when somebody creates an account. This is currently my view:

```
from django import forms
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.mail import send_mail

CARRIER_CHOICES =(
    ('@txt.freedommobile.ca', 'Freedom Mobile'),
    ('@txt.luckymobile.ca', 'Lucky Mobile'),
    ('none', 'None'),
    )

class RegisterForm (forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField()
    check_password = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
    phone = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
    carrier = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CARRIER_CHOICES, required=False)

def register (request):
    form_error = 'none'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            check_password = form.cleaned_data['check_password']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
            carrier = form.cleaned_data['carrier']
            phone = str(phone)
            if password == check_password:
                phone_email = phone + carrier
                user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
                user.is_staff = False
                user.is_active = True
                user.is_superuser = False

                send_mail(
                    'TachlisGeredt.com Account',
                    'Congrats! You have succesfully created an account with TachlisGeredt.com!',
                    'contact@tachlisgeredt.com',
                    [email],
                    fail_silently=False,
                )
            return redirect ("/register/success")
    else:
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
    return render (request, 'register.html', {'form':form})
```

I'ver tried making cookies a million different ways but its really confusing. They all seem to need me to make a variable called 'response', do 'response.set_cookie' or whatever the command is, and then do 'return response'. How do I avoid that, because I am already using 'render' to render a template, and I don't get how this 'response' thing would integrate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

```py
def some_view(request):
    response = render(request, 'some_template.html')
    response.set_cookie(key='have_a_cookie', value=1337)
    return response
```

See [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.set_cookie) for other parameters (e.g. `expires`) you may wish to set.

Comment: But how do I integrate that into the view I posted above? I don't uderstand what a 'response' is.

Comment: You know how you `return render(request, 'register.html', {'form':form})` in your view? Replace `return` with `response =` then continue like in the example above. `response` is the name of the variable holding the `HttpResponse` object returned by the `render()` shortcut. See https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/shortcuts.py